# Ansible - Getting List Values from within a Dictionary (Regsiter Variable)

Tags: ansible

So I'm working on some audit points using Ansible for many of the servers we support. In most cases, I have had to use the shell modules to get the data I want and then write some files based on pass/fail cases. In a lot of situations, this has been the easier way to work with the output data. First, I realize this isn't necessarily Ansible's forte. I guess at some point it was pitched to the company that it could do this pretty easily, and I would agree - it's easier in many ways than just writing a custom python/BASH script to do the same. So - I do realize I'm bending the concept of Ansible a bit here for reporting, rather than configuration/state management. However; I like the tool and want to show the company we can get a lot of value from it.

While I could do this section easily using the shell module, I would like to learn Ansible a bit better. So thought I would post this question.

I'm using the Yum module to just get a repolist on the target hosts. But I've been running into confusion on just how to extract the list values nested in the output dictionary. I have done some checking on the types and as far as I can tell - the 'results' variable is a dictionary, with the output in in a list. What I want to do, is get the key/values from the list and then perform some other tasks based on that output. But for the life of me - I can't figure out how to do this!

Ideally - I would like to either use some 'when' module statements based on the output (When the repo ID is.. do this.. for example) or at least be able to store them in a variable to work with the data. So from this output, I just want to get the repoid and if it's enabled. How can I get these values from the nested list?

Simple Playbook:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: yes
  tasks:

  - name: Section 1.1 - Check Yum Repos
    yum:
      list: repos
    register: section1_1

  - name: Debug
    debug:
      var: section1_1
```

Here is my output from the debug task in this playbook:

```
TASK [Debug] ****************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "section1_1": {
        "changed": false,
        "failed": false,
        "results": [
            {
                "repoid": "ansible",
                "state": "enabled"
            },
            {
                "repoid": "epel",
                "state": "enabled"
            },
            {
                "repoid": "ol7_UEKR6",
                "state": "enabled"
            },
            {
                "repoid": "ol7_latest",
                "state": "enabled"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I suspect this might be easy for someone out there. I've been trying this and that's for quite a while now and finally got to the point where I thought I would just ask :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the output of registered in `section1_1` is a list of dictionaries. We can loop through each item, to get the dictionary keys.

Example:

```yaml
- name: Get the first repo's repoid and state
  debug:
    msg: "Repo ID: {{ results[0]['repoid'] }}, is {{ results[0]['state'] }}"
# This will show -- Repo ID: ansible, is enabled
```

Similarly we can access other elements with their number.

Or we can loop through each element of array:

```yaml
- name: loop through array and conditionally do something
  debug:
    msg: "Repo ID is {{ item.repoid }}, so I am going to write a playbook."
  when: item.repoid == 'ansible'
  loop: "{{ results }}"
```

Comment: Awesome, I think that's just what I need. I did find I could get to the items using the [index] - and now I can see how to handle that in a loop.

I did have to use 'variable.results' from register to make it work right (section1_1.results). But that did the trick!

loop: "{{ section1_1.results }}"

I think I get that now - Thank you! :)

Answer (score 4):

Q: **"*Get the key/values from the list.*"**

A: There are more options. Given the data below

```yaml
  section1_1:
    changed: false
    failed: false
    results:
    - repoid: ansible
      state: enabled
    - repoid: epel
      state: enabled
    - repoid: ol7_UEKR6
      state: enabled
    - repoid: ol7_latest
      state: enabled
    - repoid: test
      state: disabled
```

1a) Get the keys and values, and create a dictionary

```yaml
  _keys1: "{{ section1_1.results|map(attribute='repoid')|list }}"
  _vals1: "{{ section1_1.results|map(attribute='state')|list }}"
  repos1: "{{ dict(_keys1|zip(_vals1)) }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  _keys1: [ansible, epel, ol7_UEKR6, ol7_latest, test]
  _vals1: [enabled, enabled, enabled, enabled, disabled]
  repos1:
    ansible: enabled
    epel: enabled
    ol7_UEKR6: enabled
    ol7_latest: enabled
    test: disabled
```

1b) The filter *items2dict* gives the same result

```yaml
  repos2: "{{ section1_1.results|
              items2dict(key_name='repoid', value_name='state') }}"
```

1c) The filter *json_query* gives also the same result

```yaml
  repos3: "{{ dict(section1_1.results|
              json_query('[].[repoid, state]')) }}"
```

Iterate the dictionary

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "Repo {{ item.key }} is {{ item.value }}"
      loop: "{{ repos1|dict2items }}"
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
  msg: Repo ansible is enabled
  msg: Repo epel is enabled
  msg: Repo ol7_UEKR6 is enabled
  msg: Repo ol7_latest is enabled
  msg: Repo test is disabled
```

2. The next option is the conversion of the values to boolean

```yaml
  _vals4: "{{ section1_1.results|
              json_query('[].state.contains(@, `enabled`)') }}"
  repos4: "{{ dict(_keys1|zip(_vals4)) }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  _vals4: [true, true, true, true, false]
  repos4:
    ansible: true
    epel: true
    ol7_UEKR6: true
    ol7_latest: true
    test: false
```

Iterate the dictionary

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "Repo {{ item.key }} is enabled: {{ item.value }}"
      loop: "{{ repos4|dict2items }}"
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
  msg: 'Repo ansible is enabled: True'
  msg: 'Repo epel is enabled: True'
  msg: 'Repo ol7_UEKR6 is enabled: True'
  msg: 'Repo ol7_latest is enabled: True'
  msg: 'Repo test is enabled: False'
```

3a) The list of the enabled repos can be easily selected

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "Repo {{ item.key }} is enabled"
      loop: "{{ repos4|dict2items|selectattr('value') }}"
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
  msg: Repo ansible is enabled
  msg: Repo epel is enabled
  msg: Repo ol7_UEKR6 is enabled
  msg: Repo ol7_latest is enabled
```

3b), or rejected

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "Repo {{ item.key }} is disabled"
      loop: "{{ repos4|dict2items|rejectattr('value') }}"
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
  msg: Repo test is disabled
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    section1_1:
      changed: false
      failed: false
      results:
        - {repoid: ansible, state: enabled}
        - {repoid: epel, state: enabled}
        - {repoid: ol7_UEKR6, state: enabled}
        - {repoid: ol7_latest, state: enabled}
        - {repoid: test, state: disabled}

    _keys1: "{{ section1_1.results|map(attribute='repoid')|list }}"
    _vals1: "{{ section1_1.results|map(attribute='state')|list }}"
    repos1: "{{ dict(_keys1|zip(_vals1)) }}"
    repos2: "{{ section1_1.results|
                items2dict(key_name='repoid', value_name='state') }}"
    repos3: "{{ dict(section1_1.results|
                json_query('[].[repoid, state]')) }}"

    _vals4: "{{ section1_1.results|
                json_query('[].state.contains(@, `enabled`)') }}"
    repos4: "{{ dict(_keys1|zip(_vals4)) }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: section1_1

    - debug:
        var: _keys1|to_yaml
    - debug:
        var: _vals1|to_yaml
    - debug:
        var: repos1
    - debug:
        var: repos2
    - debug:
        var: repos3
    - debug:
        msg: "Repo {{ item.key }} is {{ item.value }}"
      loop: "{{ repos1|dict2items }}"

    - debug:
        var: _vals4|to_yaml
    - debug:
        var: repos4
    - debug:
        msg: "Repo {{ item.key }} is enabled: {{ item.value }}"
      loop: "{{ repos4|dict2items }}"
    - debug:
        msg: "Repo {{ item.key }} is enabled"
      loop: "{{ repos4|dict2items|selectattr('value') }}"
    - debug:
        msg: "Repo {{ item.key }} is disabled"
      loop: "{{ repos4|dict2items|rejectattr('value') }}"
```

Comment: I'm a sucker for more ways to do things. Now you've given me logic to geek on for hours. Thanks Vladamir. Needless to say, I ran upon some of your comments on other related subjects (always helpful by the way). I find that with Ansible - often I need to change the way I think of building the logic, as opposed to Python, for instance. This will be a tremendous help!