# Ansible JSON query, gather one field from JSON output

Tags: json, linux, bash, ansible

I am trying to gather only 'hostname' objects from JSON output in Ansible, the following output:

```json
"json": {
    "items": [
        {
            "clusterRef": {
                "clusterName": "xxx",
                "displayName": "xxx"
            },
            "commissionState": "COMMISSIONED",
            "hostId": "xxxxxxx",
            "hostUrl": "xxxxxxxxxxxx",
            "hostname": "xxxxxxxxxxx",
            "ipAddress": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
            "maintenanceMode": false,
            "maintenanceOwners": [],
            "numCores": 4,
            "numPhysicalCores": 4,
            "rackId": "/default",
            "totalPhysMemBytes": 16655110144
        },
        {
            "clusterRef": {
                "clusterName": "xxx",
                "displayName": "xxx"
            },
            "commissionState": "COMMISSIONED",
            "hostId": "xxxxxxx",
            "hostUrl": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
            "hostname": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
            "ipAddress": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
            "maintenanceMode": false,
            "maintenanceOwners": [],
            "numCores": 8,
            "numPhysicalCores": 4,
            "rackId": "/default",
            "totalPhysMemBytes": 33194958848
        },
```

My playbook looks like this:

```yaml
---
- name: API
  hosts: localhost
  become: false
  vars:
    server: "servername"
    endpoint: "endpoint"
  tasks:
    - name: Connecting to CM API
      ansible.builtin.uri:
        url: "{{ server }}{{ endpoint }}"
        method: GET
        validate_certs: false
        user: admin
        password: admin
        return_content: yes
        headers:
            Content-Type: "application/json"
      register: result

    - name: Listing information about all hosts
      ansible.builtin.debug:
        msg: "{{ result }}"
```

I would like to have output like:

```
hostname1
hostname2
hostname3
etc.
```

I did a lot of things, but without success :(

Comment: In your debug task => `msg: "{{ json.items | map(attribute='hostname') }}"`

Answer (score 0):

Based on your provided  JSON output, a minimal example

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

  - include_vars:
      file: result.json
      name: result

  - debug:
      msg: "{{ result.json | json_query('items[*].hostname') }}"

  - debug:
      msg: "{{ result.json['items'] | map(attribute='hostname') }}"
```

will result into the requested output of

```yaml
TASK [debug] *****
ok: [localhost] =>
  msg:
  - xxxxxxxxxxx
  - xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

**Similar Q&A and Documentation**

- [Ansible `json_query` to filter data on dict of list of dict](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64659736/6771046)
- [Ansible - Getting list values from within a dictionary (regsiter variable)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64614617/6771046)
- [Selecting JSON data: JSON queries](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/docsite/filter_guide_selecting_json_data.html)